# Trying create db using ant

Tags: postgresql, ant

My build.xml

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<project xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" name='myTest' basedir='.' default='usage'> 
<property file='build.properties' /> 
<property name='src.dir' value='src' /> 
<property name='web.dir' value='war' /> 
<property name='build.dir' value='${web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes' /> 
<property name='name' value='myTest' />
<property name="sql.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
<property name="sql.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tbook"/>
<property name="sql.user" value="postgres"/>
<property name="sql.pass" value="admin"/>
<path id='master-classpath'> 
    <fileset dir='${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib'> 
        <include name='*.jar' /> 
    </fileset> 
    <!-- We need the servlet API classes: --> 
    <!-- * for Tomcat 5/6 use servlet-api.jar --> 
    <!-- * for other app servers - check the docs --> 
    <fileset dir='${appserver.lib}'> 
        <include name='servlet*.jar' /> 
    </fileset> 
    <pathelement path='${build.dir}' /> 
</path> 
<target name='usage'> 
    <echo message='' /> 
    <echo message='${name} build file' /> 
    <echo message='-----------------------------------' /> 
    <echo message='' /> 
    <echo message='Available targets are:' /> 
    <echo message='' /> 
    <echo message='build --> Build the application' /> 
    <echo message='deploy --> Deploy application as directory' /> 
    <echo message='deploywar --> Deploy application as a WAR file' /> 
    <echo message='resolve --> retrieve dependencies with ivy' />
    <echo message='' /> 
</target>
<target name="createDB_PostgreSQl">
      <sql driver="${sql.driver}" 
           url="${sql.url}" 
           userid="${sql.user}" 
           password="${sql.pass}"
           src="db.sql">
           <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
    </sql>
   </target>

   <target name="dropDB_PostgreSQl">
      <input message="Do you really want to delete this table (y/n)?" validargs="y,n" addproperty="do.delete" /> 
      <condition property="do.abort"> 
            <equals arg1="n" arg2="${do.delete}"/> 
      </condition> 
      <fail if="do.abort">Build aborted by user.</fail> 
      <sql driver="${sql.driver}" url="${sql.url}" userid="${sql.user}" password="${sql.pass}" >
           <classpath>
            <pathelement location="postgresql-9.0-802.jdbc4.jar"/>
           </classpath>  
           drop database sample_project;
      </sql>
   </target>
<target name="createTables_PostgreSQL">
      <sql driver="${sql.driver}" url="${sql.url}" userid="${sql.user}" password="${sql.pass}" >
           <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
           <transaction src="user.sql"/>
      </sql>
   </target>
<target name='build' description='Compile main source tree java files'> 
    <mkdir dir='${build.dir}' /> 
    <javac destdir='${build.dir}' source='1.5' target='1.5' debug='true' 
        deprecation='false' optimize='false' failonerror='true'> 
        <src path='${src.dir}' /> 
        <classpath refid='master-classpath' /> 
    </javac> 
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete includeemptydirs="false">
        <fileset dir="build/" includes="**/**"/>
    </delete>
</target>

<target name='deploy' depends='build' description='Deploy application'> 
    <copy todir='${deploy.path}/${name}' preservelastmodified='true'> 
        <fileset dir='${web.dir}'> 
            <include name='**/*.*' /> 
        </fileset> 
    </copy> 
</target>


<target name="resolve" description="retrieve dependencies with ivy">
        <ivy:retrieve />
</target>

<target name='deploywar' depends='build' 
    description='Deploy application as a WAR file'> 
    <war destfile='${name}.war' webxml='${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml'> 
        <fileset dir='${web.dir}'> 
            <include name='**/*.*' /> 
        </fileset> 
    </war> 
    <copy todir='${deploy.path}' preservelastmodified='true'> 
        <fileset dir='.'> 
            <include name='*.war' /> 
        </fileset> 
    </copy> 
</target> 
</project>
```

Exception is:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:ERROR: CREATE DATABASE can not be executed inside a transaction block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this thread from the past. http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2005-11/msg00132.php

Basically for the create db task add this autocommit="true"

Comment: Creating a database isn't SQL. Unlike the SELECT and CREATE DOMAIN statements, CREATE DATABASE isn't covered by any of the SQL standards, AFAIK.  I'm pretty sure that's why it can't be part of a multi-statement transaction.

Comment: Exactly, in theory if you put autocommit to false and don't issue an explicit begin transaction it should allow the correct context. Based on the PG docs "CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed inside a transaction block."  So in theory issue it in a non-transaction block context and it should work.